# How to fix "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added" in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I'm trying to display my RecyclerView into a fragment, which is inside a TabLayout.

I am new to this and don't get what to do for fixing it. While debugging I get:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
        viewPager.adapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```

MainActivity

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> FragIn()
            1 -> FragProd()
            2 -> FragShelf()
            else -> FragIn()
        }
    }
```

getItem()-function in my PagerAdapter

Comment: Please include the full exception with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> FragIn()
            1 -> FragProd()
            2 -> FragShelf()
            else -> FragIn()
        }
    }
```

Just check what is in  the method of 'FragIn()', you will get a repeated fragment if there is not a `new fragment`.